# Spin Clarification

Tags: cricket, technique, spin

In comparing the bowling technique of Nathan Lyon and Graeme Swan, are both described as "wrist" spinners OR is Swan a "finger" spinner and Lyon a wrist spinner?

It seems to me that Lyon's delivery differs sufficiently from Swan's to suggest that he derives his turn (as Warn) from the the wrist?

If Lyon is a wrist spinner, does this mean that his off break is correctly termed as a "wrongun"?

Answer (score 1):

No, both of these players are finger spinners and both right handers (so can unambiguously be described as bowling offbreaks). They in fact have, in relative terms, similar actions. They are among the few 'traditional' off spinners left in the game at the International level, in that they both only bowl the regular offspinner and the arm ball, but no schmancy doosras or caroom balls that most 'finger spinners' tend to bowl these days.

Source, cricinfo profile pages for [Nathan Lyon](http://www.espncricinfo.com/the-ashes-2013-14/content/player/272279.html) and [Graham Swann](http://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/content/player/20431.html).